# Unusual behavior of Shopping Cart (Drupal Commerce)

Tags: 7, commerce, sessions

I am using Drupal Commerce for a portal & I am facing a issue which is re-producible on fresh instance as well.

Suppose if I have a account on a website and I am logged in. I add some items to my cart and leave. It will remain in my cart even if I login from another system.

But if I don't login from another system at start & click "Add to Cart", item get added to my cart with help of session. Now if I login into system, only current items are in cart, not which I have added from another system in my account.

I mean, we loose those items which were in cart before.

This behaviour I checked on some other ecommerce website as well, but they add session cart into the account cart once you login.

What can be the solution of this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is the default behavior in Drupal Commerce, as it is supporting the idea of "multiple carts", so when you log in you get the items that you've got in your current cart and the other cart will be kept in the "background".

In fact, if you end the purchase you have once logged in, you'll most probably see that the items you had in the cart in the first place are back in there.

I'm afraid this is something you can't solve without some coding or rules, the theory here is that on the user login event, you get all the past orders from that user and combine them in the current cart of the user. This is not something you normally want as the cart pulled might be old.

Comment: Yes you are right. I found this after I asked this question. But I am still struggling in a condition where user reach to checkout for current cart but don't go forward, then he loose old cart :(

Comment: For reference, see this duplicate issue in the Commerce queue: https://drupal.org/node/2145173

Rajeev, please only post a support request in one location next time. Now we have duplicate content in a closed issue that will never help anyone else. :-/

Answer (score 0):

According to me the best solution would be to automatically logout or close the session after  pre-defined period of time. 
For that the 2 modules which can be used are as follows:

[Session Limit](https://drupal.org/project/session_limit)

> Session Limit allows administrators to limit the number of
>   simultaneous sessions per user.
>
> Max session is configurable, no database tables needed.
>
> By default, a session is created for each browser that a user uses to
>   log in. This module will force the user to log out any extra sessions
>   after they exceed the administrator-defined maximum.
>
> Assuming the session limit is 1, if a user is logged in to a Drupal
>   site from their work computer and they log in from their home
>   computer, they would be forced to either log off the work computer
>   session, or abort their new login from home.

[Automated logout](https://drupal.org/project/autologout)

> This module provides a site administrator the ability to log users out
>   after a specified time of inactivity. It is highly customizable and
>   includes "site policies" by role to enforce logout.
>
> Features Different timeouts based on role Disabling of timeouts based
>   on role Permission for users to set their own timeout Includes some JS
>   mechanisms to keep uses logged in even if multiple tabs are open or if
>   the user is working on a form for a long period of time. Includes
>   developer hooks to allow users to remain logged in depending on your
>   own project specific requirements Optional integration with Javascript
>   Timer

Comment: Thanks for taking your time & responding. But this can't solve the issue as it's not the session issue. Even if I log out from current session & start adding items in cart at another system, I loose the previous cart items once I log in.

Comment: maybe u may require some combination of user and session to solve the issue

Comment: I think it's not related to current session but the old items in cart :)